# Why does the behavior of Backspace change in vim with SSH?

Tags: vim

When I'm accessing one particular machine through ssh, the behavior of Backspace in vim changes. Instead of deleting chars, i have a ^? .

The problem is this machine acts as gateway and this problem is propagated when i'm accessing any machine behind this gateway (when I'm ssh-ing any of these machines inside the domain -without going through the domain-, i don't have this problem)...

This is not a big deal but it's really annoying.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 9):

It's usually a mismatch between what's configured in you shell and what's configured in your terminal emulator.

Some use backspace (0x08), some use DEL (0x7f). If, from within your terminal session, you run

```
stty -a
```

you'll see a line like:

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; ...
```

That erase is the DEL character. You need to either configure your SSH to transmit that character or do a:

```
stty erase '^H'
```

to change the shell.

I know that Putty, for one, can change the character transmitted when you hit the backspace key. I think it's buried in the terminal section somewhere (at least in v 0.58) but I don't have Windows handy to check it.

However, it's not *really* programming-related so you may find this gets shifted over to superuser.com.

Comment: thanks... i knew it was not "really" programming-related but I didn't know from where the error stems.

Comment: It's under Terminal->Keyboard->"The BackSpace Key" in case anyone is having trouble finding it